# laravel error when import css/js file

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

Currently, i used laravel and bootstrap template on my web page.
but when i want to import my css to my php file, i've some error

here my import code :

```
<link href="{{ URL::asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

but, i got an error

```
The requested resource /%7B%7B%20URL::asset('css/bootstrap.css')%20%7D%7D was not found on this server.
```

previously, i do the same way to import my css, and its works.

Comment: Did you upgraded from version 4 to 5?

Comment: no, i did'n upgraded it. it still the same version

Comment: Did you checked for file permissions? Alternatively try with URL::to().

Comment: i've been checking it, and try URL::to(), but it's not change :)

Comment: Try this... HTML::style will link to your project/public/ folder

{{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap.css') }}

Comment: it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Make sure your file has at least 444 or 644(everybody can read) permissions. And the path is <<ProjectFolder>>/public/css/bootstrap.css

Comment: Also try without php `<link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Comment: Chech if you file encoding is utf8 and that public/css/bootstrap.css exists.